# Play 2 How to get DataPart from MultipartFormData

Tags: playframework-2.0

How to get a DataPart from MultipartFormData? I could not find any API to get that.

```
Http.MultipartFormData formData = body.asMultipartFormData();

// simple form field
// there is NO getData() or something available
DataPart imageIdPart = formData.getData("dataKey");

// uploaded file
FilePart imagePart = formData.getFile("imageKey");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not used to work with Java in Play 2.0, but is something like that working ?

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class)
public static Result index() {
    Http.MultipartFormData multipartFormData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

    //ask the multipart to be form url encoded... 
    //and get the data
    String[] data = multipartFormData.asFormUrlEncoded().get("dataKey");

    //which should not impact such call
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart image = multipartFormData.getFile("imageKey");

    return ok("Got image: " + image.getFilename());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In scala:

```
def index = Action(parse.multipartFormData) {
    request => {

     val dataKey = request.body.dataParts.get("dataKey")
     something something...

     Ok("Ok!")
}
```